I am curious about the time complexity of search and ranking in Lucene
I am curious about the time complexity of search and ranking in Lucene.
I understand that Lucene supports search using IndexSearcher. IndexWriter builds and stores the documents in an inverted index data structure. Thanks to the inverted index, I understand that searching for the word “apple” can be done in O(1) time complexity to retrieve all related documents (n documents).
TopDocs topDocs = shardSearcher.search(query, 10);
With the code above, we can rank and retrieve only 10 out of n documents. I understand that ranking is done using algorithms like TF-IDF. I assume the necessary data structures for these algorithms are pre-built before the search. In this case, I am curious about the time complexity of ranking.
•   We need to calculate the TF-IDF score for n documents: O(N)
•   We need to sort the scores: Using a priority queue (Min-Heap of size 10), this would be NlogK.

If the number of documents (n) is very large, say over a billion, wouldn’t the NlogK time complexity for each search be a performance burden?
Based on what I found, I understand that in the worst case, it might still be necessary to check all documents. However, Lucene uses various optimization techniques such as skip lists, block skipping, early termination, and priority queues, which allow it to efficiently find the top 10 results in most cases without scanning all documents.
Is this correct?

You are right basically correct.
If the number of documents (n) is very large, say over a billion, it will be really slow for each search.
But in nowdays, we use distributed conponents to improve speed. you should depoly your data (which is very large, say TB) to many nodes, and search in every nodes, then gather the search result to generate what you want.
